# Unreserved characters in URLConnection to an FTP server

Tags: android, url, ftp, urlconnection

I have an android application that uses URLConnection to download a file from an FTP server.
My code looks like this:

```
try {
    String urlString = "ftp" + "://" + URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8") + ":" + URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8") + "@" + address + ":" + port + filepath + file;

    Log.d(TAG, "downloadAndBroadcastSpeed: "+urlString);
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

    long timeDifference;
    byte data[] = new byte[4094];
    int count;

    while (inputStream.read(data) != -1) {
        //handle inpust stream...
    }
    clearInputStream();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    clearInputStream();
    Log.d(TAG, "downloadAndBroadcast: finally");
}
```

I have tried to encode the username and password (that has special characters such as !"#€%&/()=?_*^) using `URLEncoder.encode()` with "UTF-8". But it seems doesn't work. I have an exception at `getInputStream()`:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to connect to server: Unable to log in to server (PASS): 94.237.32.84
```

Does someone have any ideas?

Comment: `protocol` What is protocol? Please dont use variables which you did not define and assigened a value too. Should we guess?

Comment: `....+ port + filepath + file;` Any separators used? We cannot see what you do!

Comment: It would look like this: `ftp://ftpuser:abc1234%20%21@32.233.12.32:21/home/ftpuser/1gbfile`